# Quickly Application making it run on startup

Tags: python, application-development, startup, quickly, pygtk

I have a PyGtk application that I made using Quickly, and I would like to have it run on startup when installed. How would I go about doing this? I'm not sure if sticking the `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/` would make it work or not. If that will fix it, I don't know how to add it to that folder since Quickly packages the project for you and has it's own installation script. Is it possible to modify what it does on installation?

If possible, I would also like to add the program in the System Settings Personal tab, but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have it run on start-up for everyone, you should install an autostart file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` as per the [XDG Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could modify Quickly's install script to add the .desktop file to that folder?

Comment: If the script is a standard Python setup.py, then you would add the appropriate info to the data_files argument to setup(), as specified in the distutils documentation: http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files